# Impact of deleting editProfile.jsp page in SelfCare portlet of WebSphere Portal Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

There is a security flaw reported in editProfile.jsp page of Selfcare portlet of WebSphere Portal Server. To fix it, the jsp page should either be deleted or have restricted access. Could someone please help with the purpose of SelfCare Portlet and editProfile.jsp page and what is the impact if it is deleted.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could someone please help.

Comment: Could anyone shed some light on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Better to open a PMR with IBM because, modifying these will have an impact while applying the Cummulative fix.